# How to update the Data Source connection string using PowerShell in the XML file

Tags: xml, string, powershell, connection

I am trying to automate to update the data source in a `web.config` file with new values using PowerShell.

Here is my connection string:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="abcLogging" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\abc; Trusted_Connection=True; Persist Security Info=True; Enlist=true; Initial Catalog=abcLogDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

PowerShell script:

```bsh
$newstring = '"Data Source=(test)\abc; Trusted_Connection=True; Persist Security Info=True; Enlist=true; Initial Catalog=abcLogDB" '
$oldstring = '"Data Source=(local)\abc; Trusted_Connection=True; Persist Security Info=True; Enlist=true; Initial Catalog=abcLogDB" '
$XmlDocument = [xml](Get-Content "D:\abc\Web.config");
$value = $XmlDocument.configuration.connectionStrings.add.connectionstring 
$value = $value -replace "$oldstring","$newstring" | Set-Content -PassThru
```

I have got the following error when I ran the above script.

```
The regular expression pattern "Data Source=(local)\abc; Trusted_Connection=True;
Persist Security Info=True; Enlist=true; Initial Catalog=abcLogDB"  is not valid.
At line:5 char:1
+ $value = $value -replace "$oldstring","$newstring" | Set-Content -Pas ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ("Data Source=(l...og=OnityLogDB" :String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code you posted doesn't throw the error you claim it does.

Comment: I am still having the same issue, i couldn't update my connection string with the above script

Comment: I tested the code you posted with the data sample you posted, and it does not throw the error shown in your question. Did you try from a clean PowerShell instance (run `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoExit` from CMD)? Does the problem occur there as well?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Hari Krishna! There are a few things going on with your script.

1. There are too many quotes in your old and new strings - the old string will not be found. Generally, single quotes should be used unless there is an embedded `$variableName` to be expanded with its value.
2. The parentheses are being treated as regular expression special characters because you are using the `-replace` syntax. The `[string]` object's `.Replace` method can be used for a simple replace without regular expression.
3. The `Set-Content` command doesn't know what file to act on. But you don't really want to set the content of the file to only be `$value`.  That would get you a file with none of the XML content and only the connection string.

Here's a script that should do what you want:

```
$configFile = 'C:\temp\web.config'

Set-Content -Path $configFile -Value @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="abcLogging" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\abc; Trusted_Connection=True; Persist Security Info=True; Enlist=true; Initial Catalog=abcLogDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
"@

$newstring = 'Data Source=(test)\abc; Trusted_Connection=True; Persist Security Info=True; Enlist=true; Initial Catalog=abcLogDB'
$oldstring = 'Data Source=(local)\abc; Trusted_Connection=True; Persist Security Info=True; Enlist=true; Initial Catalog=abcLogDB'

$XmlDocument = [xml](Get-Content $configFile);
$XmlDocument.configuration.connectionStrings.add | %{
    If($_.connectionString -eq $oldstring){
        $_.connectionString = $newstring
    }
}
$XmlDocument.Save($configFile)
Get-Content -Path $configFile
```

EDIT: corrected issues found during additional testing.

Comment: Thank you Rich for your detailed response, I have got the following error,                                                          
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "abc\Web.config", for "WriteContentTo" to type "System.Xml.XmlWriter": "Cannot convert the 
"D:\abc\Web.config" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlWriter"."
At line:6 char:1
+ $XmlDocument.WriteContentTo($ConfigFile)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Comment: When i add $XmlDocument.Save($ConfigFile) instead of $XmlDocument.WriteContentTo($ConfigFile), no error however, the value inside the file doesn't get updated

Comment: That's odd. What version of Powershell are you using? Try running `$PSVersionTable` at a Powershell prompt and reply with the results. I've successfully tested the script above in PSVersion 4.

Comment: My version 5.1 PowerShell

Comment: Did you copy the script above _exactly as written_? The error message indicates that `$configFile` has an incorrect value. Also, I concur with @Ansgar-Wiechers' suggestion to try a new Powershell window.

Comment: Yes, i copied the script exactly also tried the script from new powershell window, but end up with same issue

Comment: I think xmldocument doesnt have any value when i ran the echo  $XmlDocument command, throwing   "xml     #comment  configuration
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ...                                                                                                                                   configuration

Comment: Is the $configFile path correct? Does that file exist and is it a normal web.config?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that question, what do you mean by normal web.config, it is part of web application

Comment: I've corrected a couple issues and made an easily verifiable example. Please remove the `Set-Content` command and change the `$ConfigFile` path.